# how to crawl semantically similar sentences

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, sentence-similarity, semantic-analysis

I want to create a corpus for a machine learning task. I have a small textual dataset and want to crawl similar sentences from web. I used sentence_transformers package with Bert pertained model, doc2vec and spacy similarity to measure similarity. I set the threshold to 85%, but the sentences with the similarity score higher than the threshold weren't really relevant. how can I crawl similar sentences from web in python?

Comment: Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions, please. Right now your question is not focused enough to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should train a big model on a big corpus and then use that model to generate random sentences. The `gensim` library has several `corpora` [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.html) that you can use to find similar sentences or to train a model that generates similar sentences , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781292/doc2vec-get-most-similar-documents) is how to do it.